# Palindrome won't output correcly

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, methods

When I compile the program is comes up with the error exception in thread "main"

I I don't know why.   I'm trying to create a program that allows the user to input a word and then output whether or not the word is a palindrome

```
import java.util.*;

public class Palindrome{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String word=getWord();
       boolean w=isPalindrome(word);
       if(w==true)
           System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome");
       else
           System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome");
    }

    public static String getWord(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in ); 
        String word;                                                                               
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        word=keyboard.nextLine();
        return word;
    }

   public static boolean isPalindrome(String word){
       int y=word.length();
       for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
          if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(y-i)
             return false;
        }
        return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: The title of this question should be i have a compiler error. Debug my code for me. You got an error; of course output will be wrong if there is any. Sorry if that sounds snarky but your title implies a fault in logic while your question is focused on a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line `if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(y-i)`  is obviously missing right round bracket.

`if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(y-i))` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement, presumably on that line, lacks a closing paren

Comment: Basically OP needs to look at his code at line 33, and count matching parentheses. Hmmmm....